# Adding Dynamic URL in StyleBundle BundleConfig

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification, dynamic-url

I am creating a Dynamic CSS from Razor to modify the URLs that are included in the system.

So basically, I have a CSS result on this link ~/layout/customzh

However, when I add it into the bundle configuration, it doesnt work:

```
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/cssmainch").Include(
                    "~/Layout/CustomZH"
                    ));
```

It cannot see the resource that I have attached.

Can anyone help me solving this one?

Thanks!